# App crashed when I try to map through and render data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Please tell me what the problem is here, I get data on restapi and in mapStateToProps I filter the data on input into the field and everything is fine console.log (cardList) displays what it should but how do I add this map - cardList.cards.map to display data, the app crashes.
If I remove this map, then again the data will be in the store and the app runs correctly.
I do not understand how the presence of a cycle does not allow to receive data in the store. please tell me

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import { getCards, findTags } from '../../actions/SessionActions'

import './Home.css'
import Sort from "./Sort/Sort";
import Filter from "./Filter/Filter";


class Home extends Component {
    state = {
        sortSelect: ''
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.onGetCards();
    }

    handleTableSort = (e) => {
        this.setState({sortSelect : e.nativeEvent.target.selectedOptions[0].text});
    }

    findTag = (e) => {
        this.props.onFindTags(e.target.value);
    }


    render(){
        let cardList = this.props.cards;

        // if(this.state.sortSelect === 'Likes'){
        //     cardList = this.props.cards.sort((a, b) => a.likes - b.likes);
        // }
        // else if(this.state.sortSelect === 'Comment'){
        //     cardList = this.props.cards.sort((a, b) => a.comments - b.comments);
        // }


        console.log(cardList);

        return(
            <div className={'card-list'}>
                <div className={'card-list__controls'}>
                    <Filter findTag={this.findTag.bind(this)}/>
                    <Sort handleTableSort={this.handleTableSort.bind(this)}/>
                </div>
                <div className={'card-list__head'}>
                    <div className={'card-list__head_row'}>Image</div>
                    <div className={'card-list__head_row'}>Tags</div>
                    <div className={'card-list__head_row'}>Likes</div>
                    <div className={'card-list__head_row'}>Comments</div>
                </div>
                {
                    cardList.cards.map((card) =>
                        <div className={'card-list__item'}>
                            <div className={'card-list__item_row card-list__item--img'}>
                                <img src={card.webformatURL} alt=""/>
                            </div>
                            <div className={'card-list__item_row card-list__item--tags'}>
                                <div className={'tags-wrap'}>
                                    {
                                        card.tags.split(', ').map((tag) =>
                                            <span>{tag}</span>
                                        )
                                    }
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div className={'card-list__item_row card-list__item--likes'}>
                                <span>{card.likes}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div className={'card-list__item_row card-list__item--comments'}>
                                <span>{card.comments}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    cards: state.cards.filter(cards => cards.tags.includes(state.filterCards)),
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    onGetCards: () => {
        dispatch(getCards())
    },
    onFindTags: (name) => {
        dispatch(findTags(name))
    }
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);



//filterCards


import { FIND_TAGS } from '../actions/SessionActions.js'

const initialState = '';

export default function filterCards(state = initialState, action) {
switch (action.type) {
    case FIND_TAGS:
        return action.payload
    default:
        return state
}
}
```

Comment: Where is your ```state.filterCards``` at? I'm assuming it's filtering back an empty array due to nothing being true.

Comment: Shouldnt it be `cardList.map` instead of `cardList.cards.map`?

Comment: @RajenderJoshi No, in cardList there is a field cards

Comment: @Mark I added reducer filterCards in bottom. but there is all correct because without map it works, store has a data and when i add this map, store is empty, i don't know why

Comment: This is an asynchronous call to an API correct? Is your app crashing when you add the map?  You need to add a conditional before it something like ```cardList && cardList.cards.map...``` otherwise it will try to map and when there's no data crash.  The component will re-render when the props passed to it change aka when you actually receive the data from your asynchronous call.

Comment: @Mark yes this is an asynchronous. App crashing when i try render carts info in map without this map store has a data but when i add map store is empty

Comment: I guess I don't know what you mean the store is empty.  How can you even tell if your app is crashing?  Add a conditional and it should work.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: @Mark i tried put this cardList && cardList.cards.map instead of this cardList.cards.map and didn't help

Comment: is cardList an array?  Try ```cardList.length &&```

Comment: @Mark oooh with cardList.length && cardList.map helped!!! thank you so much

Comment: Nice.  I just added an answer to your question.  I'm glad I could help!

Comment: Feel free to select it as the correct answer =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are receiving data from an asynchronous function you need to leverage a conditional to only render once the data has been received.   You will not have any data on the initial render until the promise has been fulfilled, hence your program crashing.

There are a few ways to do this and you can read more about that here https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html.  My preferred method in your case would be to use `cardList.length &&`.

I updated your code below to use this logic.

```
    render(){
        let cardList = this.props.cards;

        return(
            <div className={'card-list'}>
                <div className={'card-list__controls'}>
                    <Filter findTag={this.findTag.bind(this)}/>
                    <Sort handleTableSort={this.handleTableSort.bind(this)}/>
                </div>
                <div className={'card-list__head'}>
                    <div className={'card-list__head_row'}>Image</div>
                    <div className={'card-list__head_row'}>Tags</div>
                    <div className={'card-list__head_row'}>Likes</div>
                    <div className={'card-list__head_row'}>Comments</div>
                </div>
                {
                    cardList.length && cardList.cards.map((card) =>
                        <div className={'card-list__item'}>
                            <div className={'card-list__item_row card-list__item--img'}>
                                <img src={card.webformatURL} alt=""/>
                            </div>
                            <div className={'card-list__item_row card-list__item--tags'}>
                                <div className={'tags-wrap'}>
                                    {
                                        card.tags.split(', ').map((tag) =>
                                            <span>{tag}</span>
                                        )
                                    }
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div className={'card-list__item_row card-list__item--likes'}>
                                <span>{card.likes}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div className={'card-list__item_row card-list__item--comments'}>
                                <span>{card.comments}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )
                }
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```